# Azure DevOps Pipeline task DownloadPackage@1 omits nuget package version

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I have an Azure DevOps artifact feed that hosts NuGet packages. I am trying to download a NuGet package from it using a Pipeline task DownloadPackage@1.

`

```
- task: DownloadPackage@1
  inputs:
    packageType: 'nuget'
    feed: 'RandomFeed'
    definition: 'MyPackage'
    version: '1.0.0.0.'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

`

When I download it manually from the feed or with API, the package is downloaded with its full name and version appended - MyPackage.1.0.0.0.nupkg

When I try to use the DownloadPackage@1, the downloaded package has it's version omitted and only the title remains - MyPackage.nupkg

Is there a way to download the nuget from the feed with its full name ? I target to use the integrated Pipeline tasks so I can use the System.AccessToken for the Pipeline and not use additional ones for example to fetch it from the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the ***System.AccessToken*** for pipeline to authorize, you can only use the ***DownloadPackage task*** in pipeline.

For using ***PAT (Personal Access Token)*** to authorize, you can first create a service connection credential for the feed.

[image]

Add ***NuGet authenticate task*** in the pipeline.
[image]

Then use ***PowerShell task*** in line script to download NuGet packages.
The inline script:
`nuget install {package name} -version {package version} -Source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_packaging/{feedname}/nuget/v3/index.json`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am trying to avoid using PAT since it's tied to a user, but it is a viable workaround.

Comment: You can try to set nuget source first, then run the nuget install command.